# speed up nptdms channel.read_data() or .to_dataframe()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, labview

I'm working in Python and trying to read **.tdms** files with the **nptdms** package.
I want to extract the data from a channel, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html#module-nptdms), I use:

```
channel.read_data()
```

and also tried:

```
channel.to_dataframe()
```

Both options are painfully slow!
Some of my channels have 1.8kk lines and just this step takes about 174 seconds.

Do you know how to do this faster?
It would be great for me to have the channel data in a pandas dataframe afterwards.

Thanks for the advice and help!

as described above: I tried the options described in the documentation.

```
channel_data = channel.read_data()
channel_data = pd.DataFrame({'value': channel_data})
```

and

```
channel_data = channel.as_dataframe(time_index=False, absolute_time=False, scaled_data=True)
```

I timed the code with pythons time.time() befor and after.